# Special values of real analytic Eisenstein series

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms, eisenstein-series

Given $\tau$ in the upper half plane, define the normalized real-analytic Eisenstein series by
$$
E(\tau, s) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{(m,n)}' \frac{y^s}{|m\tau + n|^{2s}}
$$
It is initially defined for $\text{Re} (s) > 1$, but then analytically continued to the whole plane, except for a simple pole at $s=1$.

What are some known special values of this function? The only known values I have seen on the internet are $E(i, s) = 4 \zeta(s) \beta(s)$.  I am especially interested in $E(\tau, 0)$ for any other values of $\tau$.

Comment: For fixed $\tau$ in the upper half-plane, the function $s\to E_s(\tau)$ is also called an _Epstein_ _zeta_ _function_, easily google-able. The sum of these values over $\tau$ running through Heegner points for a given negative fundamental discriminant produces $\zeta_k(s)/\zeta(2s)$, where $k$ is the corresponding complex quadratic field extension of $\mathbb Q$. This was known to Hecke. Other linear combinations of special values at Heegner points produce ideal-class characters of those fields. Values at "generic" $\tau$ seem to be much less well-understood.

Comment: ... and the idea of "periods of Eisenstein series" is a well-established thing, going back to Hecke and Maass, and more examples in recent years. Erez Lapid and various of his collaborators have done many examples. Rankin-Selberg integral expressions for various L-functions can be considered examples of such periods. In this vein, Deligne's Corvallis (1977, AMS 1979) piece about special values is relevant. But/and what is the question?

Comment: Ok, that's interesting, thanks. But nevertheless, my question still isn't answered. I would like to know a list of known special values of $E(\tau, 0)$ for certain $\tau$. Or any special values whatsoever, for arbitrary $s$. You have talked about linear combinations, not values at specific points.

Comment: To give one example, the residues of the Eisenstein series appear in the computation of the fundamental domain of $G/\Gamma$ done by Langlands.

Comment: The more natural objects are suitable linear combinations (over Heegner points) giving special values of ideal-class group L-functions, from which the individual values can be recovered by linear algebra. Values at $s=0$ are residues at $s=1$, which are non-zero only for the trivial ideal-class character. For general points $\tau$, but at $s=0$ or $s=1$, over $\mathbb Q$ we have the Kronecker limit formula.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful. I'd just like to know the final answer though, without having to do the linear algebra myself. Just want to know the explicit value of eg. $E(1 + i,0)$. Seems such explicit formulae are not listed anywhere.

Comment: Probably they are not listed because they are not hard to compute whenever one wants, at least to the extent possible, for the Heegner-point cases. E.g., $E_s(1+i)=E_s(i)=\zeta_k(s)/\zeta(2s)$ for $k=\mathbb Q(i)$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $E(\exp(\frac{2 \pi i}{3}), 0)$.

Comment: With a cube root of unity, the outcome is still $\zeta_k(s)/\zeta(2s)$, now with $k$ the corresponding quadratic extension.

Comment: Thanks Paul, much appreciated. But I still just want to know the answer, what is $E(\exp(\frac{2 \pi i}{3}), 0)$? I don't know much about Dedekind zeta functions and I don't know the explicit value of $\zeta_k(0)$ for the relevant $k$ here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combining paul garret's comments (see also his wonderful notes, [Standard compact periods for Eisenstein series](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/eis_std_periods.pdf)) with the class number formula, the functional equation of the Dedekind zeta function and the fact that $\zeta(0)=-1/2$, we get:

$$E(\tau,0)=\frac{\zeta^*_K(0)}{\zeta(0)}=\frac{2h_KR_K}{w_K}$$

where $h_K$ is the class number, $R_K$ the regulator and $w_K$ the order of the group of roots of unity of $K=\mathbb{Q(\tau)}$.

From here it should be very tractable computation for any reasonable $\tau$.